# The use of the word 'welcome'

Tags: vocabulary

We used the word 'welcome' as many things, i.e. adv, adj, noun... we may say:

You are welcome here. [adj]

We welcome you here. [verb]

Welcome home! [excl]

Thank you for your warm welcome. [noun]

Can we use this word as a tag, such as in greetings?

> The king's arrival, welcome!

Comment: What situation do you imagine using such a slogan?  "The king's arrival" seems very odd to put on poster or sign. Who do you imagine will be reading the slogan? The king? Slogans are usually using in advertising to persuade someone to choose something.  How is this a "slogan"?

Comment: let me correct myself, i meant  greetings

Comment: Well of course you can use it in a greeting, that is the main meaning of the word.  But in "The king's arrival, welcome", who are you addressing?  The king? The word welcome is fine for a greeting (see your example 1, 2 and 3 in which it is used as part of a greeting)  So again, what is the situation?

Comment: The king is coming, someone says: The King's arrival... the rest say: welcome. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, use "welcome" a greeting.  It is a greeting on its own as an exclamation (your third example), and it is part of a greeting in examples 1 and 2.  So the answer to the main question is, yes, it *is* a greeting and you've used it as a greeting.

Your situation with "The king's arrival" doesn't work. You announce someone by their name or title:  "His majesty the King!". You wouldn't say "The king's arrival" to announce the arrival of the king.  While it is possible for the rest to welcome the king by saying "Welcome! as an exclamation, it's not really done. People might bow, or clap, or call "God save the King!"